# JavascriptMVC: how do I invoke the Controller's history methods?

Tags: javascriptmvc, uri-fragment

JMVC has a History plugin that lets you interact the URL's hash fragment.  For example, you can change the #hash part of the URL to make certain actions inside your app bookmarkable, and allow people to navigate using the browser's back button.

Unfortunately, I'm not having much luck using it.

The following code creates a JMVC controller that tries to set the browser URL to something like `example.com/myApp#controller/someController`.  However, nothing happens because the **redirectTo()** method that the History plugin says it defines, is undefined.  I've also tried **History.redirectTo()**.

```
steal.plugins("jquery/controller/history");
$.Controller.extend('MyControllerWithHistory', {}
{
'.item click': function( el ){
   redirectTo({controller:'someController'});
}
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll get the best responses to JMVC questions on the official forum: http://forum.javascriptmvc.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `this.redirectTo()`:

```
steal.plugins("jquery/controller/history");
$.Controller.extend('MyControllerWithHistory', {},
{
'.item click': function( el ){
    this.redirectTo({controller:'someController'});
}
});
```

By including the history plugin you are adding methods such as `redirectTo` to `$.Controller`.

Comment: *groan* of course! Moving from Java to Javascript is hard.  Thanks, Martin!